# Gradle in Kotlin project with private repository fails build with Intellij but builds fine through command line

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project running Gradle with Kotlin. I am using a private repository and have changed `settings.gradle.kts` and `build.gradle.kts` accordingly to accommodate:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://my-private-repo.com/maven")
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}
```

In my `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` I have added the distribution URL:

```
distributionUrl=https\://my-private-repo.com/distros/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
```

The build runs fine initially (when using IntelliJ), downloading everything, but in the end, I get this message regarding the build failure:

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve gradle:gradle:7.6.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://services.gradle.org/distrobutions/gradle-7.6-src.zip'.

When I run it using `./gradlew build` at the terminal, it builds successfully. It's a fresh project generated through [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/).

Comment: Do you have an internet connection?

Comment: Yes, but gradle.org is blocked and only the private repository is accessible.

Comment: Intellij tries to download `gradle-7.6` as used in in your Gradle wrapper file

Comment: I see the download progress being done and it downloads it successfully at the beginning. It's only when it's time to build that it tries to download it from gradle.org for some reason, even though I set it to use the properties from gradle-wrapper.properties. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changed the line in the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and the dists in the `%USER%\.gradle\wrapper\dists\*`. I then had to change the distribution URL as follows:

```
-distributionUrl=https\://my-private-repo.com/distros/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
+distributionUrl=https\://my-private-repo.com/distros/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

The solution was found as per the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18249